# Setting parameters of kernel modules before loading

Tags: linux, module, kernel

In order for the wifi adapter in my laptop to function properly, I need to run the following commands

modprobe -r rtl8732be

modprobe rtl8732be ant_sel=1

Setting the parameter ant_sel does not work without unloading the kernel module. I'm trying to make this process at boot time but with no success.

- Making a service that execute this code and enabling it didn't work. It throws an error while booting.
- Putting the parameter's value in a .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/ did't work.

$ cat rtl8732be.conf

options rtl8732be ant_sel=1

$ ll -Z rtl8742be.conf

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:modules_conf_t:s0 28 Apr 12 09:56 rtl8732be.conf

- I'm not using modules-load.service

I guess, it is because the module has to be removed before setting the parameter ant_sel.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the syntax you used for the `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d`? Was it `options module_name parameter_name=parameter_value`? Are you using systemd - in particular, systemd-modules-load.service?

Comment: I edited the question to provide this info